# typescript, access static member

Tags: javascript, typescript, static

I am want to have such thing - Api.drinks.info -> which is static and returns string. But I have an error [image: this]

```
module App {
export class Api {
    public static drink: Drink;
}

class Drink {
    static get base(): string { return '/api/drink'; }
    public static get info(): string { return `${Drink.base}/info`; }
}}
```

How can I fix it or implement? Thank you.

UPDATE

---

One of possible solutions

```
module Api {
export module Drink {
    var base = '/api/drink';
    export var info = `${base}/info`;
}
export module Admin {
    var base = '/api/drink';
    export var info = `${base}/info`;
}}
```

Answer (score 0):

`Api.drink` is not `Drink`, the class (constructor), which is what has `info`; it's an *instance* of `Drink`, which does not. The line trying to access it is trying to use the instance as though it were the class.

You don't export `Drink`, so the only way to access it is really roundabout:

```
this.resource = this.dataAccessService.getResource(Api.drink.constructor.info);
```

...But it would be better to export `Drink` and use it directly:

```
this.resource = this.dataAccessService.getResource(Drink.info);
```

Note that the code quoted never assigns a value to the `drink` instance, so you'll need to do that with either of the above.

---

Alternately, perhaps you intended to expose `Drink`, the constructor, as a static member of `Api`? If so, you need to change things up a bit, see comments:

```
module App {
    // Classes aren't hoisted, so this needs to be before Api
    class Drink {
        static get base(): string { return '/api/drink'; }
        public static get info(): string { return `${Drink.base}/info`; }
    }

    export class Api {
        // 1. It's a function
        // 2. We're initializing it to Drink
        // 3. Because it's a constructor function / class, we use an
        //    initial capital letter in its name
        public static Drink: Function = Drink;
    }
}
```

Then:

```
this.resource = this.dataAccessService.getResource(Api.Drink.info);
```

Comment: It was not a method it was property. So I can access it without ().

Comment: I found how I can implement it via modules, module Api {
    export module Drink {
        var base = '/api/drink';
        export var info = `${base}/info`;
    }
    export module Admin {
        var base = '/api/drink';
        export var info = `${base}/info`;
    }
}

Comment: @ovasylenko: Yup, that's what I meant by *"But it would be better to export `Drink` and use it directly:"* (Sorry, missed the `get` on `info`.)

Comment: @t-j-crowder Thank you for the help!

Comment: @ovasylenko: I think you mean `export class` in that, btw. If this *answered* your question, the way SO works, you'd accept the answer by clicking the checkmark next to it, which takes it off the list of unanswered questions.

Comment: @t-j-crowder. It help me in my case, but still I want to know how it can be done in other ways.